# Всё это я уже пробовал - не помогает

Tags: обсуждение

Что делать с тем, что ответ не подходит автору вопроса по причине того, что он не указал, что всё это он уже пытался сделать? Непреднамеренно, конечно же, никакого злого умысла не было.

Стоит ли в таких случаях удалить ответ и попросить топикстартера внести изменения в вопрос?

Прекрасно понимаю, что "мы пишем ответы не только для спрашивающего – но и для тех, кто потом придёт в базу знаний из поиска". Но тут ведь проблема именно в том, что умолчав о существенных подробностях вопроса получается как бы и совершенно другой вопрос хоть и по смежным темам – и ответы могут быть существенно разными.

Comment: Я хотел бы обсудить вопрос в общем виде, поэтому конкретный пример привожу в комментариях, а не в теле вопроса. [Вот ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/783080/213987) тем, кто считает, что нужно обсуждать конкретный пример. Непреднамеренность налицо: автор даже задавал уточняющие вопросы на гитхабе.

Comment: Я в такой ситуации часто пишу в конце текста ответа **Update** и далее отвечаю в соответствии с новыми обстоятельствами

Comment: Обычно «не помогает» означает, что у автора вопроса нет MCVE, и он требует угадать, где у него ошибка, не предоставив нужный код. С хорошо сформулированными вопросами такого не бывает. Ставьте минус и переходите к следующему вопросу.

Comment: @VladD, почему не ответ?

Comment: @Grundy: Не бинайсно же.

Comment: @VladD а я не считаю правильным минусовать, автор просто не знал, не подумал, или не понимал на тот момент определённые моменты, это не повод минусовать, мы же не ракету в космос запускаем, нельзя с авторов вопросов как и с авторов ответов требовать 100% идеальности. Если я в слове пропустил букву, да ошибка, ну и что с того, это что повод минусовать?

Comment: @VladD но с другой стороны когда пишешь ответ 20 минут например, а потом автор вопроса говорит что это уже пробовал... это обидно может быть... а ещё бывает помогаешь автору, а он огрызается за то что его твой ответ не устроил, и минуса ставит... Так что думаю минус вопроса тоже может быть вполне заслужен...

Comment: Я за то что бы добавлять в конце вопроса дополнение под UPDATED. Потому что 1. ответ даётся не только тому кто спрашивает 2. как-то обидно удалять свои труды. 2 я понимаю что моё субъективное желание, но тем не менее....

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин: Автор должен уважать работу отвечающих. Допустим, автор задал вопрос, на который получил правильный ответ. Если после этого автор заявляет «я это уже пробовал, мне это не подходит» — он, очевидно, ни во что не ставит внимание отвечающего к его вопросу. Пропущенное слово не является проблемой. Но если ответ на вопрос _в том виде, как он поставлен_, дан, неплохо бы этот ответ принять, а не требовать у отвечающих угадать, почему правильное решение у автора не работает, и какой из альтернативных подходов сработает.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин: Если автор по ответу понял, что его вопрос на самом деле другой, он должен не редактировать вопрос, инвалидируя ответ (или хуже того, минусовать правильный ответ!), а принять ответ, и задать _новый_ вопрос.

Comment: @VladD Да, это было бы более правильным, и с точки зрения SO и с точки зрения вложенных трудов отвечающего.